# One word for 'choking environment'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word for an environment where people feel choked. For example, the environment in medieval Europe (or in communist era) was far from free. One felt choked/strangulated. Is there is word to describe such an environment?

For eg, for happiness, one could say An era/regime of happiness. What would that be for choked?

**Update**: I was trying to say that the age of Enlightenment was a response to a 'choking kind of environment' where the church had too much control over people's lives.

Comment: Claustrophobic.  Oppressive.  Toxic.

Comment: Just added an update. Thanks.

Comment: @DJohnson Claustrophobic I was thinking, but didn't find it apt.

Comment: You ask for a single word (I've altered the tag accordingly; the politics domain is almost certainly over-restrictive – a suitable word would be usable in other situations). But ths rules out say 'a **stifling** / an **oppressive** [situation etc]'. Please add a sample sentence with an underscored space for the missing word; it must be a noun according to the title.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I am new to English Stackexchange, so I was not aware of this Tag. Thanks a ton for changing it to this appropriate one.

Comment: Can you explain why you don't like claustrophobic rather than just dismissing it without any reasons? The word is very commonly used metaphorically ([see M-W's examples](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/claustrophobic)).

Comment: Well, the criteria for the dismissal of this word is not based on a *reason*, but rather on *feeling*. The feeling for a word is developed based on its usage. The corresponding texts, which I have read have moslty used the word *Stifling*, rather than *Claustrophobia*, and that's why when @LPH posted it, I could immediately associate with it. Thus, this forms the basis of its "dismissal", if you want to put it bluntly, but there is nothing wrong with the word *Claustrophobia* and can be used interchangably.

Comment: A sample sentence with an underscored space for the missing word; it must be a noun according to the title? Or if an adjective will do, "One word **to describe** a 'choking environment": you can add [adjective] and/or [noun] tags as you require.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"*Stifling*" should do.

> ([Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stifling%5D))
> 2. adjective
> If a situation is stifling, it makes you feel uncomfortable because you cannot do what you want.

([Political Dissent and Democratic Remittances: The Activities ... Joanna Fomina · 2021](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Political_Dissent_and_Democratic_Remitta/BlQ-EAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22stifling+political%22&pg=PT13&printsec=frontcover)) They have been joined by others who did not face immediate danger yet were tired of the stifling political atmosphere, the aura of doom and gloom and the lack of visible perspectives for change.

([The Dynamics of Political Communication: Media and Politics ...
Richard M. Perloff · 2021](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/The_Dynamics_of_Political_Communication/kogzEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22stifling+political%22&pg=PT254&printsec=frontcover)) Trump's supporters loved his feisty, take-no-prisoners style, finding it a long-overdue antidote to stifling political correctness.

([Vietnamese State Industry and the Political Economy of ... - Adam Fforde · 2007](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Vietnamese_State_Industry_and_the_Politi/uQWkAgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22stifling+political%22&pg=PA45&printsec=frontcover)) Failure to combine political reforms with privatisation and economic liberalisation in 1990–1991 kept the country trapped within a stifling political framework.

Comment: The moment I saw your answer, I knew that *stifling* was the word I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Good. Could also add *suffocating.*

Answer (score 0):

These words suit particularly for your examples around how the state treats its populace...

#### Subjugation

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/subjugate

> to defeat people or a country and rule them in a way that allows them no freedom

Used in your example phrase it would be:

"An era/regime of subjugation"

or

### Repression / Repressive

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/repression

> the use of force or violence to control a group of people:

"An era/regime of repression"